# Gauss's thesis: Theory of equations or hypergeometric functions, or both?

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, math-history, hypergeometric-function

I had read in multiple places, and always believed, that the first good proof of the fundamental theory of algebra (that a polynomial of degree $n$ over $\Bbb{C}$ has $n$ roots, with suitable treatments for multiple roots) was provided by Gauss's doctoral thesis.

But it is also stated (for example, in Concrete Mathematics) that Gauss's dissertation presents many of the subtle properties of hypergeometric functions with two upper and one lower index (which are now called "Gaussian Hypergeometric Functions").

It is certainly plausible that a thesis contains multiple loosely-related topics; my thesis in Supergravity was like that.  Still, these two topics are two towering results, and I naively can find no connection between them at all. For all I know, there may be other important results in the same thesis as well. Which brings me to my real question:

**Is there a readable translation of Gauss's doctoral dissertation/thesis?**

Comment: Another link https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd8ZOs_v_NAhVLQ48KHTf6Cy4QFgg3MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.quantresearch.info%2Fgauss_phd_dissertation.pdf&usg=AFQjCNECHiEZAue0v3LD3ZD7cTX1It8zig&sig2=TSzWn8QSGmvKIT6EbypTOw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a good translation.  Gauss' original writing is a little old fashioned but still perfectly readable.

http://archive.larouchepac.com/node/12482

The flaw doesn't have anything to do with hypergeometric functions as far as I know.  The trouble is he assumes without proof that a real algebraic curve that enters a circle must leave it again.

Comment: The site you refer too is "less than neutral" (understatement) ! Don't you know another site, say less "oriented" where the same information is avalable ?

Comment: It's a direct translation...  Are you saying the translator's Latin is biased somehow?

Comment: I thought I was clear enough... Unbiased scientific content in a biased site (have a look at the content of this "Larouche" site). But that's all. No relationship with the quality of the translation.

Comment: The "topological" flaw you mention is interesting ; do you know if there is a "fully clean" (may be comtemporary) proof along the lines of Gauss (at least this proof because, he has produced others)  ? I am fascinated by figures 1 to 4 at the end of the document. This vision looks so new for his time. For me it bears similarity with the revolutionary views of Poincaré with his quasi-periodic orbits, one century later. Geniuses at work...

Comment: @JeanMarie Apparently Ostrowski was the first to fix it up in 1920.  Here's the paper, if you can read German: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN236019856|LOG_0053&physid=PHYS_0310

Comment: Thank you very much, Lance Sackless, for this reference. I should find my way although it's in German...

Answer (score 2):

The [MacTutor biography](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Gauss.html) mentions "[Disquisitiones generales circa seriem infinitam](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/EKMSCJAVYSZUHLAAOWE4MCWIV4UQT2P5)" as introducing the hypergeometric functions.  This was not his doctoral thesis: it is dated 1812.  His doctoral dissertation "[Demonstratio Nova Theorematis Omnem Fvnctionem Algebraicam Rationalem Integram Vnus Variabilis In Factores Reales Primi Vel Secvndi Gradvs Resolvi Posse](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/XHCMC3DFPPLK4LVOU2TKFOJUHDUJ43KY)" from Helmstedt was in 1799, and was about the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.

Comment: Aha, then Knuth, Graham and/or Patashnik had it wrong in COncrete Mathematics. Although they do cite the 1812 work that you mention, not his 1799 dissertation. And they call it a "Thesis delivered to the Royal Society in Gottingen." I upvoted your answer but gave @Lance Sackless the check because his link to the translation is exactly what I wanted to find.

Comment: A "thesis" is not always a document written for the purpose of obtaining a degree.  I guess "monograph" might have been a better choice of words in this case though.